# Regex isMatch for cache pattern key

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I wrote test for my cache extension. I want to delete from cache by pattern.

a) In this example test fails

```
 [Test]
    public void Should_found_by_pattern()
    {
        string pattern = "shouldFoundThis-{0}-{1}-{2}";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var keysToRemove = new List<String>();

        var list = new List<string>()
        {
            "shouldFoundThis-15-2-7"
        };

        foreach (var item in list)
            if (regex.IsMatch(item))
                keysToRemove.Add(item);

        keysToRemove.Any().ShouldBeTrue();
    }
```

b) In this example test passes

```
 [Test]
    public void Should_found_by_pattern()
    {
        string pattern = "shouldFoundThis-{0}-{1}";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var keysToRemove = new List<String>();

        var list = new List<string>()
        {
            "shouldFoundThis-15-2"
        };

        foreach (var item in list)
            if (regex.IsMatch(item))
                keysToRemove.Add(item);

        keysToRemove.Any().ShouldBeTrue();
    }
```

Why Regex IsMatch doesn't match pattern "shouldFoundThis-{0}-{1}-{3}" but matches pattern "shouldFoundThis-{0}-{1}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex `shouldFoundThis-{0}-{1}-{2}` is identical to the regex `shouldFoundThis---`, and there are no three dashes in sequence to be found in your subject string.

In constrast, `shouldFoundThis-{0}-{1}` is the same as `shouldFoundThis-` which *can* be found in your string.

In a regex, `x{n}` means "`n` repetitions of `x`". Read more about [quantifiers here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

You probably meant something like

```
string pattern = @"shouldFoundThis-\d+-\d+-\d+";
```

Comment: Exactly. The passing test was an interesting false positive http://regex101.com/r/yM4iM6/1

Comment: Good answer, but I can't use shouldFoundThis-\d+-\d+-\d+ because I formatting my pattern like strin.Format(UsersCachePattern,usersTypeId,dateFrom)

Comment: @Anjmao: I don't understand the problem.